# Does H2 spawn a new thread for each remote connection? Then, is there a limit?

Tags: java, database, h2

I am developing an online mobile game. I have several server machines running numerous instances of a Java socket server application.

Player data has to be stored somewhere (their profiles, items etc). I want to use the H2 database for this purpose.

Now, here's the tricky part: I want all the player data to be stored in the same H2 database. That is, all my server applications will access the data by remotely connecting to one particular machine over TCP, out of convenience.

The thing is, we are expecting a very large amount of clients on launch. For each client, a connection to the H2 database is created. The obvious concern here is whether one single H2 database process can handle so many connections concurrently.

From [the website](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes):

> There is no limit on the number of database open concurrently per
>   server, or on the number of open connections.

Given the above fact, in theory, if our server machine has enough resources (memory, space, CPUs, etc), then yes, the H2 database should be able to handle as many concurrent connections as our resources allow.

But there is something unclear to me:

Does the H2 process create a thread for each remote connection? I ask this because I once read that  in Windows (our VPS' OS), a thread is stored as a short type, and hence the max amount of threads an application can spawn is roughly 32,000 (I don't know the math they used to get that number). In that case, then the H2 process does have a limit of concurrent connections - which is troubling because I do indeed expect more than 32,000 clients connected.

Of course, it would seem wise to discard the idea of having one single H2 database for all my clients. But I'd like to know if the above statement is correct: **can H2 handle more than 32,000 remote database connections?**

Comment: Using single database for all clients is fine. But accesing database directly from clients not so. Better create some server application, then it would connect to database using only some pool  of connections, and your clients would connect to server.

Comment: @Kamil.H, well, when a client connects to my server application, it would create a new thread: wouldn't I run into the same issue if I had more than 32,000 clients connecting to my server application?

Comment: I was expecting that kind of answer. :-) It is hard to say if a server can handle so many connections. You should do some benchmarking with different servers. Modern java servers support non-blocking IO, meaning they don't create new thread per connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let take this by parts:

"***Does the H2 process create a thread for each remote connection?***"

An application should normally use one connection per thread. An H2 database synchronizes access to the same connection, but other databases may not do this.

"***can H2 handle more than 32,000 remote database connections?***"

If you want to access the same database at the same time from different processes or computers, you need to use the client / server mode. The `JdbcConnectionPool` class has the default maximum number of connections set to 10, but it provides a setter to change it if you want.  In theory, you can set it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but I don't think this is wise.  Why? For starters, the synchronization point made on the previous section.  Another point to consider is if your application opens and closes connections a lot (for example, for each request), you should consider using a connection pool. Opening a DB connection is very slow.

"***Of course, it would seem wise to discard the idea of having one single H2 database for all my clients***"

It might be, but you have to keep in mind that the number of open database is limited by the memory available. If you are running on a powerful server, it might be a good option to consider.  Then again, it might not.

Comment: What does it mean that H2 synchronizes access to the same connection?

Comment: I see. But what if my clients do indeed change information in the database at the same time? By the way, I've been playing around, making several connections from my laptop to the server, and apparently each connection does indeed spawn a new thread in the server.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment when what I meant was to edit. Here it goes: H2 is multithreading-safe. That means, if an application is multi-threaded, it does not need to worry about synchronizing access to the database. Internally, most requests to the **same database** are synchronized. That means an application can use multiple threads that access the same database at the same time, however if one thread executes a long running query, or is updating information, the other threads will be blocked. Thread scheduling takes care of the rest.

Comment: I hope you find this information useful. I am not a backend person or a test engineer. I am just a developer. This is about to the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks - do you think it makes a difference to have one `Connection` object for each thread, or can all threads use the same `Connection` object?

Comment: It does. That is the first point on my thread. H2 database synchronizes access to the same connection. To be totally honest, this is how we use H2 database, so I am not sure what mechanisms (if any) exist to synchronize data across multiple database instances. My guess is that it is not trivial. But I do not know.